# Why my code changes don't take effect in editor UE4?

Tags: c++, unreal, debugging

I have a [plugin](https://www.unrealengine.com/marketplace/en-US/product/runtime-transformer-tool-gizmo) in my project to move around stuff with gizmos(much recommended tool, by the way).
It has quite a few blueprint functions that I use.
I would like to add some functionality to it, though.

So I opened up the related cpp files, namely TransformerPawn.cpp and had a look around, and found a few starting points where I can add GEngine debug messages, to see what is going on...

I chosen a few blueprintcallable functions and went ahead by:

- added those debug messages, but they do not take effect at all...
- added some other code(move the actor 1000000 units away in tick), but still nothing...
- commented out code, but blueprints kept working...

I added the Engine.h header in my cpp. I also tried rebuilding the solution...
And yes I hit compile every time... :D

To test things out I added an empty C++ actor, and added a blueprintcallable function to it to print out debugmessages(GEngine), and it worked as it should be... I can see the debug messages...

EDIT: I use [Rama's Victory plugin](https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/blueprint-visual-scripting/4014-39-rama-s-extra-blueprint-nodes-for-you-as-a-plugin-no-c-required) a lot. I added a custom BP node there, recompiled it, and it didn't work...
But the new plugins available message popped up in the bottom right corner!
So I disabled, and enabled it and it did work. I could see my new BP node. :)

Later on I test it with the above asset and update the post.